# Firestore security rules read array length

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I created my Firestore rules

```
     match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
   
      allow read, 
            update, 
            delete: if request.auth != null 
                    && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null 
                    && request.auth.uid == userId
                    && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role<6
                  //&& get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles_array.length <6
    }
```

and the line

```
&& get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role<6
```

works OK, but the line with array length

```
&& get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles_array.length <6
```

doesn't work and I have permission error

Below database screen

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`.size()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#size) to get length of array. Try:

```
get(<DOC_PATH>).data.roles_array.size() < 6;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have just had argument with chatGPT - it believes length should work and still thinks like that even when I said the size() works only:)

Comment: just encase you haven't worked it out - ChatGPT does not know code, it makes it up on the spot based on what it assumes is code. it sees array and javascript and assumes 'length' is the default and correct answer - it cannot cite any source or documentation.